# Given Cartesian coordinates for 3 points (x,y,z) how to find the angles between the lines formed

Tags: geometry

Three lines (red, blue, green) formed based on the three given points
[image: Three lines (red, blue, green) formed based on the three given points]

How do I calculate the angle between origin and red (theta0), red and blue (theta1) and blue and green(theta2) using vector dot product?
The points are as follows:

```
Origin = [0 0 0];
p1 = [1 2 3];
p2 = [4 4 4];
p3 = [7 5 6];
```

Comment: $\vec{A} \cdot \vec{B} = |A||B|\cos\theta$

Comment: Do you mean to find theta 1 I would have to do:
theta1 = acos(dot(p1,p2)/(|p1|*|p2|))

Answer (score 0):

The angle $\theta$ between two vectors $\vec{a},\vec{b}$ can be calculated from the formula $ \cos \theta = \frac{ \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} }{ \sqrt{ (\vec{a} \cdot \vec{a} ) ( \vec{b} \cdot \vec{b}) } }$.

The vector from point $P$ to point $Q$ is $Q-P$. Combine these, and you can calculate the relevant angles.

Answer (score 0):

From among three given points let lengths after computation by distance formula  between $(p1,p2) $ be equal to $ (c,a) $

Connect between $ (p1,p3) $ and let its length by distance formula be equal to $b$.

Then by Cosine Rule

$$ \cos p1= \dfrac{ b^2+c^2-a^2}{ 2 b c}$$

and similarly two other angles. If negative,it is an obtuse angle.